# Calling ms graph API using browserless console python program

Tags: python, microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to hit microsoft to do list api using python program.

Api : https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/todo/lists , which resulted in error : Access is denied due to invalid credentials. But when I tried the api : https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users, I am getting the results properly. The documentation of the api (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/todo-overview?view=graph-rest-beta) says "Currently, the API supports only permissions delegated by the signed-in user". Currently I am trying to get auth code and then auth token and then hitting the API. To act as signed in user, what method should I follow in python? Please note I am not using a web frame work. When I tried using flask and then hitting the API , it works. Need to know how a browserless console python application can serve the purpose.

Thank youin advance for the help

Comment: Could you please share us the request id and timestamp for the failed request?

Comment: Thanks Shiva. please find the details :    "date": "2020-10-07T08:53:21",
      "request-id": "3b7d76d6-d4a6-4e09-bba8-d568281e0de1",

Comment: You are getting an App only token using a [client credential](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials) flow and it doesn't ask for user credentials. Please check these [Authentication flows](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) and according to your requirement you can choose one of these and implement it. In other ways you can test your HTTP call in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) by adding permissions there itself. Your call works here because you will login as user.

Comment: Thank you Shiva. I am able to hit the API now. I used this link. https://github.com/Azure-Samples/ms-identity-python-devicecodeflow

Comment: Glad to here. Moving this to Answer :)-

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are getting an App only token using a [client credential](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows#client-credentials) flow and it doesn't ask for user credentials. Please check these [Authentication flows](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/msal-authentication-flows) and according to your requirement you can choose one of these and implement it. In other ways you can test your HTTP call in [Graph Explorer](https://aka.ms/ge) by adding permissions there itself. Your call works here because you will login as user.